# How to use some attribute instead of id to create a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have two models: Album and Song. Album has album_title as its attribute and Song has song_title and album_id.
Here are the associations:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :songs, dependent: :destroy
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :album
end
```

To create a new song I need to specify album_id. What I want is the ability to create new song entering album_title in the input field instead of album_id, with album's id being stored in the database.

I was able to come up with this:

```
<%= f.select :album_id, Album.all.collect{ |a| [a.album_title, a.id] }  %>
```

It allows you to choose an album from a list and assigns its id to album_id. And while it does work for my small semester project, I'd like to know if it's possible to achieve what I initially wanted. Or should I take some different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this approach.  There are helper methods that let you do the same thing a bit cleaner, though:

```
<%= f.collection_select :album_id, Album.all, :id, :album_title %>
```

**UPDATE**

Now that I have a better understanding, you can accomplish this with a text_field_tag:

```
<%= text_field_tag :album_title %>
```

And in your controller, use `find_or_create` to get the album:

```
@song = params[:song]
if params[:album_title].present?
  album = Album.find_or_create_by_album_title(params[:album_title])
  @song.album = album
else
  @song.errors.add(:album_id, "cannot be blank")
end
```

Even better, move this logic into the song model to clean up your controller.

Comment: No, not really. I want to be able to enter a string, not to choose an item from the list. I feel like the list may grow too long over time and become unusable.

Comment: Oh, you want to avoid a select list in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, that was the idea at the start, at least.

Comment: Take a look at chozen select: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ and the rails gem: https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails @toxox

Comment: @MrYoshiji: very nifty!  You should probably post this as an answer.

Comment: @PinnyM No my comment is not answering the question and I posted my comment after I read the OP's comment "I want to be able to enter a string" and "I feel like the list may grow too long", and it is also a combination of your solution & the select

Comment: Ah! It works even better with this gem.
Thanks a lot, guys. It all works now.